# facing issue to set the data in context by making api request using React context API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am facing an issue to basically set the data in context by making api request using React context API. It's seem like data from API is not getting picked up which cause empty array data to appData in context of appState. However, api data is coming properly in AppProvder and AppContext from root App component but it's not setting the api data instead it's set empty array data.

Can you please let me what went wrong with below code.

1. AppContext.js

   ```
    export const getAppContextInit = (dataSource: string, data: any) => {
      const storedState = JSON.parse(
        window.localStorage.getItem(`${dataSource}-appState`),
      );

      // Returns the appState that is locally stored or return a new object.
      console.log('data=>', data); // able to see data from API

      // but in context, it seem like data from API is not getting picked, so appData is always []
      // storedState will be null initially as we don't have anything in local storage
      return storedState
        ? storedState
        : {
            appData: data
          };
    };

    export const AppContext = createContext<appContextType>({
      appState: {
        appData: []
      },
    });

    export const useAppContext = () => useContext(AppContext);
   ```
2. AppProvider -> Getting the data here as well from Root App component

   ```
    const AppProvider: ({ source, data, children }) => {
    console.log('data=>', data) => // data is logging from api 
    const [appState, appAction] = useReducer(
    appReducer,
    getAppContextInit(source, data),
    );
    return (
      <AppContext.Provider value={{ appState, appAction }}>
      {children}
      </AppContext.Provider>
    );
   };
    export default AppProvider;
   ```
3. appReducer

   ```
    export const appReducer = (appState) => {
    let updatedState = {
    appData: prop('appData')(appState),
    };
    const store = `${prop('dataSource')(appState)}-appState`;
    window.localStorage.setItem(store, JSON.stringify(updatedState));
    }
   ```
4. App component

   ```
    import AppProvider from '../hooks/AppProvider';
    const App = () => {
    const source = 'test';
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        'apiURL',
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      setData(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    };
     useEffect(() => {
       getData();
      }, []);
     return (
      <AppProvider source={source} data={data}>
       <Test />
      </AppProvider>
      );
     }; 

    export default App;
   ```
5. Test component

   ```
     const Test = () => {
     const { appState } = useAppContext();
     console.log('appState', appState); 
      // Actual output -> { appData: [] }
     // Expected output -> { appData: {... data from api }}
     return (
       <div>
        Test App Component
       </div>
      )
     }

   export default Test;
   ```

Here is Sandbox for this problem :- https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-wind-mzyx4f

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify your context code, try this:

```
// context.tsx
type ContextType = {
  contextData: ....
  updateContextData: (updatedData: ....) => void
}

const MyContext = createContext({} as ContextType)

export function ContextProvider({children}) {
  const [contextData, setContextData] = useState( ... )
  ...

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const dataFromAnywhere = await .....
      setContextData(() => dataFromAnywhere)
    })()
  }, [])

  ....

  function updateContextData(updatedData) {
    ... store your data anywhere
    setContextData(() => updatedData)
  }

  return (
    <MyContext.Proivder
      value={useMemo(() => ({
        contextData,
        setContextData
        ...
      }), [
        contextData,
        ....
      ])}
    >
      {children}
    </MyContext.Provider>
  )
}

export function useMyContext(): ContextType {
  const context = useContext( MyContext )
  if ( !context ) throw new Error( 'Auth context is invalid' )
  return context
}

// your_root_component.tsx
import {ContextProvider} from 'path/to/file'

...

return (
  <ContextProvider>
    <MyComponent />
  </ContextProvider>
)

// MyComponent.tsx
import {useMyContext} from 'path/to/file'

function MyComponent(){
  const {contextData, updateContextData} = useMyContext()

  ....
}
```

Comment: Created a sandbox here . I will check this one meanwhile. https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-wind-mzyx4f

Comment: It is possible to make those changes in sandbox . Plz ignore the typescript as of now, plain javascript will also work

Comment: [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-pine-76ln9t?file=/src/Test.tsx) is a working codesandbox example

Comment: You're wellcome, if I helped you please mark my answer as the sollution :D

Comment: I am trying to implement ur solution because I can't simply remove other file as they are very important for the our app. I just simplify here so that I can focus on main issue